# Busca com case insensitive

Tags: javascript, case-insensitive

Fala galera boa tarde, estou com um campo de busca porém preciso que ele retorne os valores independentemente de `toLowerCase()` e `toUpperCase()`

Ex Bola, posso procurar como **bola** ou então **BOLA**

estou com a seguinte linha de código:

```js
function filterMaterialList(query){
    let categorySelect = document.querySelector('select[name=category]');
    let materialList = materials[categorySelect.value];
    let reducedList = [];

    if(query === ''){
        return materialList;
    }

    for(let material of materialList){
        if(material.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1){
            reducedList.push(material);
        }
    }

    if(reducedList.length == 0){
        reducedList.push({name: 'Nenhum resultado encontrado!', id: null});
    }

    return reducedList;
}
```

porém como estou usando:

`if(material.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1){...`
só tenho sucesso quando pesquiso por **bola**

Preciso que essa função seja case insensitive, alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A forma mais simples/prática é passar também a *string* de consulta para o mesmo formato:

```
if (material.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1)
```

Comment: maaaaano muito obrigado vei, tava batendo cabeça aqui, salvou grandão kkkkkkkkk, já coloco como resposta correta

Comment: :D massa que resolveu

Answer (score 7):

sendo o parâmetro "query" seu critério de busca, segue sugestão: basta colocar o `query.toLowerCase()`, dessa forma, independente da forma que for informado o critério de busca, ambos serão comparados com Lower-Case.

```js
function filterMaterialList(query){
    let categorySelect = document.querySelector('select[name=category]');
    let materialList = materials[categorySelect.value];
    let reducedList = [];

    if(query === ''){
        return materialList;
    }

    for(let material of materialList){
        if(material.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) != -1){
            reducedList.push(material);
        }
    }

    if(reducedList.length == 0){
        reducedList.push({name: 'Nenhum resultado encontrado!', id: null});
    }

    return reducedList;
}
```